# How to convert a nested object to an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I convert this object

```
{
    priorities: {
        1: "categoryOne"
        2: "categoryTwo"
    }
}
```

to this array :

```
[ {1: "categoryOne"}, {2: "categoryOne"} ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take entries of object and then map it:

```js
var obj= { priorities: { 1: "categoryOne", 2: "categoryTwo" }};
var result = Object.entries(obj.priorities).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: your answer very helpful tnx